# Crystal Report 11.5 Type Initializer Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

I've got a web application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and it uses the Crystal Reports 11.5 components to print a CR report to a printer. This is all working fine but after about an hours I get the following exception: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.
When I recycle the application pool the error disappears and it will work for a an hour more before failing again. 
I'm preventing this error from occurring by recycling every 15 minutes but this isn't ideal.

IIS Application pool settings:
.NET 4.5 ASP.NET web application
.NET Framework version is set to v4.0
Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated
Enable 32-bits application: True
Identity is set to an AD user with full rights on the server

Build my project as x86.
Installed CrystalReports_XI_R2_SP4_DeploymentPack on the deployment server.

Why is the exception occurring after an hour and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my active solution was x86 but my project was still being build as AnyCPU. Changed the project also to x86 and now everything is working fine.